# How do I root huawei mobile phone?

Tags: rooting, 5.1-lollipop

This specific huawei mobile I have is known to be very hard to root or not able to be rooted at all. I will add the specs below in this description if needed.
Huawei Y538 - Android 5.1
API5.1 (22)
FLASH_SIZE8 GB

Comment: Since Huawei no longer offers bootloader unlock codes this is nearly impossible... I would suggest using Kingroot per this thread on XDA https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/huawei-union-y538-root-t3299120 but be very careful what you do after rooting... Remember that there is no bootloader unlock for this device and it has secure boot, so if you mess with the system partition (such as removing or adding applications) you may make the device unbootable and unrecoverable.

Comment: kingroot itself does modify system partition, so this is bad idea. however, you can buy unlock codes for some devices, or try `fastboot oem unlock UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU` WARNING: FACTORY RESET